# how to have generic constrained type

Tags: scala, types

I would like to represent some constrained data with scala type system, with constants.
For example in pseudo code,  what i would like to write is something like this, (and optionaly if possible, using compile-time checking the contraints)

```
val data1 : String of 10
val data2 : Int of (0..10)
val data3 : Int of (1..1000)
val data4 : String of 30

// etc.
```

without writing such code for every type :

```
type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
type @@[T, U] = T with Tagged[U]
object Tag {
  @inline def apply[T, U](t: T): T @@ U = t.asInstanceOf[T @@ U]
}

sealed trait StringOf32
object StringOf32 {
  def apply(value : String) : String @@ StringOf32 = {
    require(value.length <= 32)
    Tag(value)
  }      
  def unapply(s : String @@ StringOf32) : Option[String] = Some(s)      
}

sealed trait IntFrom0To10
object IntFrom0To10 {
  def apply(value : Int) : Int @@ IntFrom0To10 = {
    require(value >= 0 && value <= 10 )
    Tag(value)
  }      
  def unapply(s : Int @@ IntFrom0To10) : Option[Int] = Some(s)      
}

// etc.
```

Is there alrealdy exists some library wich propose this kind of construction ?
Is there a way, to have such generic construction ?
Perhaps using macros, but i'm not sure it's a good idea, and i'm not fluent with.

What do you think, in what direction should i go ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for but what I see here instantly reminds me of **[refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined)**. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [partial functions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction)?

```
val strOf10: PartialFunction[String, String] = { case str if (str.length == 10) => str};

val a = List("a", "abc", "abcdefghij");

scala> a collect strOf10
res5: List[String] = List(abcdefghij)
```